# How to parse a text file using C and get all of the ints

Tags: c, parsing, text

I am not the best C programmer, and i am trying to parse a text file that contains words and ints and I am trying to save all of the ints into different variables.  I'm having trouble skipping over all of the other characters and only getting the int's

My Text file looks like this:

`Task[0] 0, 11, 27, 53, {2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 3
Task[1] 1, 22, 49, 92, {2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 3`

```
int x = 0;
int t;
FILE *ptr_file;
int lines = 0;
int ch = 0;
ptr_file = fopen("tasks.txt", "r");
if (!ptr_file)
    return;

int i, id, readyTime, WCET, deadline, numberOfResources;
int resources[10];

while(!feof(ptr_file))
{
  ch = fgetc(ptr_file);
  if(ch == '\n')
  {
    lines++;
  }
}
while(x < lines)
{
    //gets the whole task line
    fscanf(ptr_file, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &t, &id, &readyTime, &WCET, &deadline, &resources[0], &resources[1], &resources[2], &resources[3], &resources[4], &resources[5], &resources[6], &resources[7], &resources[8], &resources[9], &numberOfResources);

    printf("Task %d, id %d, readytime %d, WCET %d, deadline %d, resources (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d) numResources %d\n", x, id, readyTime, WCET, deadline, resources[0], resources[1], resources[2], resources[3], resources[4], resources[5], resources[6], resources[7], resources[8], resources[9], numberOfResources);
    ++x;
}
fclose(ptr_file);
```

I don't think I am using fscanf properly, but can't get it to work.

Any help would be great

Comment: Perhaps some `structs` will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *input = "Task[0] 0, 11, 27, 53, {2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 3";
    const char *it = input;
    char *next;

    while( *it )
    {
        int value = strtol( it, &next, 10 );
        if( it == next )
        {
            printf( "Text: '" );
            while( *next && !isdigit(*next) ) {
                putchar( *next );
                next++;
            }
            printf( "'\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Value: %d\n", value );
        }
        it = next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Text: 'Task['
Value: 0
Text: '] '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 11
Text: ', '
Value: 27
Text: ', '
Value: 53
Text: ', {'
Value: 2
Text: ', '
Value: 1
Text: ', '
Value: 1
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: ', '
Value: 0
Text: '}, '
Value: 3
```

Note that it won't deal with negative integers, but that's easily rectified.